# Django dictionary sort by value

Tags: python, sorting

I am creating a web app that tells how many words are in the input.
I want to post the top 15 most-used words as well.

This is my code:

```py
def count(request):
    entered_text = request.GET['textarea']
    word_list = entered_text.split()
    word_dictionary = {}

    for word in word_list:
        if word in word_dictionary:
            word_dictionary[word] += 1
        else:
            word_dictionary[word] = 1
    return render(request,'count.html',
        {'alltext':entered_text, 
         'total':len(word_list),
         'dictionary':word_dictionary.items()})
```

I want to sort `word_dictionary` by value.

I tried to use the `sorted` function but it doesn't work.

Is there any ways to sort `word_dictionary`?

Answer (score 0):

What you implement here is basically a [**`Counter`** [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). A `Counter` has a [**`.most_common(…)`** method](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) to return a list of 2-tuples ordered by count. You thus can use:

```
from collections import Counter

def count(request):
    entered_text = request.GET['textarea']
    word_list = entered_text.split()
    word_dictionary = Counter(word_list)

    return render(request,'count.html', {
        'alltext':entered_text,
        'total':len(word_list),
        'dictionary':word_dictionary.most_common()
    })
```

**EDIT**: Or for the top 15 words:

```
from collections import Counter

def count(request):
    entered_text = request.GET['textarea']
    word_list = entered_text.split()
    word_dictionary = Counter(word_list)

    return render(request,'count.html', {
        'alltext':entered_text,
        'total':len(word_list),
        'dictionary':word_dictionary.most_common(15)
    })
```

Comment: I don't quiet understand.Nothing is added in word_dictionary and I want to find out top 15 most used words

Comment: @dkahfmrpTek: sorry, it was `word_counter`.

Comment: @dkahfmrpTek: you can obtaiun the top 15 with `.most_common(15)`